# Classnotfound Exception while running an executable jar

Tags: spring-boot

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: LdaCourtApplication
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

Comment: Can you share code snippet?

Comment: <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
 

    
    
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>LdaCourtApplication</mainClass>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                    
                <executable>true</executable>
            
                </configuration>

Comment: pom.xml configuration